# Theta vs. Omega

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to understand time complexity.

If you have an algorithm with a running time of θ(n^2), is it possible to have a best case running time of Ω(n)? Or is the fastest running time only some constant factor c * n^2?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, it hasn't gotten any answers. I'll try the CS stack exchange (though I know I'll get flamed for this question being too simple and remedial for the PhDs there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theta is a tight bound, meaning that it represents the worst case **and** the best case. So in your case, the fastest running time will be a constant of the tight bound.